# Python: How to search a nested list using recursion

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to search a nested list using python. For example, the function is `nestedListContains(NL, target)`. `nestedListContains([1, [2, [3], 4]], 3)` should return `True` but `nestedListContains([1, [2, [3], 4]], 5)` should return `False`.

What I tried:

```
def nestedListContains(NL, target):
   if target not in NL:
      return False
   else:
      return True
```

The examples I gave work but if it's nestedListContains([[9, 4, 5], [3, 8]], 3) then it gives me the wrong return value. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def nested_list_contains(nl, target):
    for thing in nl:
        if type(thing) is list:
            if nested_list_contains(thing, target):
                return True
        if thing == target:
            return True
    return False

print(nested_list_contains([1, [2, [3], 4]], 3))  # True
print(nested_list_contains([1, [2, [3], 4]], 5))  # False
```

Comment: I think you should check if NL is a list not length of target.

Comment: it gives me an error object of type 'int' has no length

Answer (score 2):

The following algorithm has linear runtime complexity. Differently than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35117909/1), the result is found in only one pass:

```
def search(l, target):
    for element in l:
        if isinstance(element, list) and search(element, target):
            return True
        if target == element:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Both answers here have linear runtime complexity?

Comment: That holds true before @Filip Haglund edited his answer.

Comment: No it doesn't. The old version did at most two linear passes; still O(n). I'm having trouble thinking of a way to write a slower algorithm for searching.

Comment: Your previous solution needed two passes in case of nested lists. Still linear, but two passes.

Comment: Have a look at all the answers. They are all O(n). Our answers are incredibly similar. You answer is definitely not "differently than the other solutions posted here".

Comment: So, let me ask you this: what is the runtime complexity of `if target in NL`? Now, imagine that you have only nested lists in `NL`. You will do an entire pass without finding the result. Besides having a mistake (you do a `len()` that does not make sense), it does two passes worst case. That's the only thing I'm stating here.

Comment: An entire pass, over a single element. That code was replaced with my edit 40 minutes ago.

Comment: Indeed. Your first answer motivated me to post mine.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost perfect, but where is the recursion?

```
def nestedListContains(NL, target):
   if target not in NL:
      return False # <-- HINT: hint, it should be here
   else:
      return True
```

The `not in` check only checks the highest level of nesting.

Try something like this:

```
from collections import Iterable

def nestedListContains(NL, target):
   if target not in NL:
      if isinstance(NL, Iterable):
          for sub in NL:
              return nestedListContains(sub, target)
      else:
          return False
   else:
      return True
```

Using the check for `Iterable` should make this work with other iterable classes like `set` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `type(nl) is list`, I prefer using `isinstance(nl, list)` for more generic algorithm which allows subclassing.

```
def nl_contains(nl, target):
    return isinstance(nl, list) and \
           any(item == target or nl_contains(item, target) for item in nl)
```

Here are some tests:

```
>>> nl_contains([1, 2, 3], 1)
True
>>> nl_contains([1, 2, 3], 4)
False
>>> nl_contains([1, [2], 3], 2)
True
>>> nl_contains([1, [2], 3], 4)
False
>>> nl_contains([["ab"], ["cd"]], "a")
False
>>> nl_contains([["ab", [1, 2]], ["cd"]], [1, 2])
True
>>> nl_contains([["ab", [1, 2]], ["cd"]], [1, [2]])
False
```

If you want to check with a subclass:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...    pass

>>> nl_contains(MyList(xrange(3)), 2)
True
```

In Python, we use to work with iterable objects (`list`, `set`, `dict`) or generator objects.

To check if an object is iterable, use: `hasattr(iterable, '__iter__')`.

For instance:

```
def iterable_contains(iterable, target):
    return hasattr(iterable, '__iter__') and \
           any(item == target or iterable_contains(item, target) for item in iterable)
```

Some unit tests:

```
>>> iterable_contains([1, 2, 3], 1)
True
>>> iterable_contains([1, 2, 3], 4)
False
>>> iterable_contains([1, [2], 3], 2)
True
>>> iterable_contains([1, [2], 3], 4)
False
>>> iterable_contains([["ab"], ["cd"]], "a")
False
>>> iterable_contains([["ab", [1, 2]], ["cd"]], [1, 2])
True
>>> iterable_contains([["ab", [1, 2]], ["cd"]], [1, [2]])
False

>>> class MyList(list):
...    pass
>>> iterable_contains(MyList(xrange(3)), 2)
True

>>> iterable_contains({1, 3, (5, 6), 7, 9}, (5,6))
True
>>> iterable_contains(dict(a=5, b=9), 'a')
True
>>> iterable_contains(xrange(10), 5)
True
>>> iterable_contains(xrange(10), 10)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def findX(l, x):
  if(x in l):
     return True
  # whenever we got a list explore it
  for i in l: # this part will recursively check lists (Depth First Search)
     if(type(i)==list):
        out = findX(i, x) # use recursion here
        if(out==True):# we only need Return  True from inner Lists
           return True
                #if not true go for the next list
  return False
```

Comment: can be used to find x in a multiple nested list using Recursion