# Get key from a list of values in dictionary?

Tags: python

Let's say I have:

```
ref = ['<var>', '<id>', '<expr>']
val = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a', '1+1']
dicio = dict(zip(ref, val))
```

now, I know that by doing

```
list(dicio.keys())[list(dicio.values()).index('a')]
```

It returns `<id>`. But let's say that you only had one value associated per key, so

```
val = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'b', '1+1']
```

How could I get `<var>` without listing `['a', 'b', 'c']`?
Thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark most of the bidirectional dictionary solutions won't work when the value is a list, since lists aren't hashable.

Comment: @Barmar Then the list can be transformed into a tuple instead.

Comment: @barmar Also, could a recursive solution be implemented here to traverse the values list and find the proper value?

Comment: @Cardstdani Sure, I don't see why not.

Comment: If you don't want to list `['a', 'b', 'c']` what do you want to use instead?

Comment: @Barmar Precisely what Cardstdani suggested. But I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117847/python-how-to-search-a-nested-list-using-recursion/68152990#68152990

Comment: If you search for `b` it could match either `<var>` or `<id>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `"a"` value by the `list ['a', 'b', 'c']`:

```
print(list(dicio.keys())[list(dicio.values()).index(['a', 'b', 'c'])])
```

You will get as output the value associated with the index you inserted before:

```
<var>
```

Or you can use list comprehension to traverse the list of dict values:

```
ref = ['<var>', '<id>', '<expr>']
val = [['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a', '1+1']
dicio = dict(zip(ref, val))

selectedVal = list(i for i in list(dicio.values()) if "a" in i)[0]
print(list(dicio.keys())[val.index(selectedVal)])
```

Which outputs the same as the previous solution.